# How can a variable in a list be counted?

Tags: bash

How can each occurrence of a variable in a list be counted, like how it would be if it were in a loop?

For example, in a loop, such as

```
for i {1..10}:
do
echo $1
echo hello
echo -e
done
```

the shell will output

```
1
hello

2
hello

3
etc.
```

How can I get this same sort of counted output from a non-looping list? Following the example, the list would be

```
echo $1
echo hello
echo -e

echo $1
echo hello
echo -e

echo $1
echo hello
echo -e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
idx=1
echo $idx
echo 'hello'
echo -e

idx=$((idx+1))
echo $idx
echo 'hello'
echo -e;

idx=$((idx+1))
echo $idx
echo 'hello'
echo -e
```

or maybe:

```sh
_idx=1
function countHello { echo $_idx; echo "hello"; echo -e; _idx=$((_idx+1)); }
function helloX3 { countHello; countHello; countHello; }
helloX3
```

best:

```sh
_idx=1
function countHello { echo $((_idx++)); echo "hello"; echo; }
function helloX3 { countHello; countHello; countHello; }
helloX3
```

Thanks Cyrus (comments)

Comment: The first answer works just as I'm wanting it to. Thanks for the help!

Comment: A little shorter: `function countHello { echo $((_idx++)); echo "hello"; echo; }`

Comment: Or just `printf 'hello\n%i\n\n' {1..10}`